# How to obtain Hessian from nlme call

Tags: r, nlme

```
library(nlme)
fm1 <- nlme(height ~ SSasymp(age, Asym, R0, lrc),
            data = Loblolly,
            fixed = Asym + R0 + lrc ~ 1,
            random = Asym ~ 1,
            start = c(Asym = -10311111, R0 = 8.5^4, lrc = 0.01),
            verbose = TRUE)

**Iteration 1
LME step: Loglik: -312.2787, nlminb iterations: 23
reStruct  parameters:
    Seed 
10.41021 
Error in nlme.formula(height ~ SSasymp(age, Asym, R0, lrc), data = Loblolly,  : 
  Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1
```

I am trying to investigate why some `nlme` models do not fit successfully by looking at the hessian. Is there a way to extract this matrix somehow?

I am also looking into the `fdHess` function (also from the same pacakge), which "Evaluate an approximate Hessian and gradient of a scalar function using finite differences" would this be equivalent to what is currently implemented in the function `nlme`?

Comment: Have you seen varFix from here https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nlme/html/nlmeObject.html ? A method that I used in the past to get around numerical problems, is to use different starting values, here using argument start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is caused by a poor selection of starting points. The vector `c(Asym = 103, R0 = -8.5, lrc = -3.3)` converges without any complication:

```r
nlme(height ~ SSasymp(age, Asym, R0, lrc),
     data = Loblolly,
     fixed = Asym + R0 + lrc ~ 1,
     random = Asym ~ 1,
     start = c(Asym = 103, R0 = -8.5, lrc = -3.3))

#> Nonlinear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
#>   Model: height ~ SSasymp(age, Asym, R0, lrc) 
#>   Data: Loblolly 
#>   Log-likelihood: -114.7428
#>   Fixed: Asym + R0 + lrc ~ 1 
#>       Asym         R0        lrc 
#> 101.449600  -8.627331  -3.233751 
#> 
#> Random effects:
#>  Formula: Asym ~ 1 | Seed
#>             Asym  Residual
#> StdDev: 3.650642 0.7188625
#> 
#> Number of Observations: 84
#> Number of Groups: 14
```

At the end of the day, model fitting can be understood as an optimization problem. When your model is non-linear (such as a mixed-effects model), that problem has to be solved using iterative optimization algorithm. Hence, the selection of starting value can be quite critical. Here is a nice scientific article discussing this topic:

> Balsa-Canto, E., Alonso, A.A. & Banga, J.R. An iterative identification procedure for dynamic modeling of biochemical networks. BMC Syst Biol 4, 11 (2010) doi:10.1186/1752-0509-4-11

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing to do here is to have a look at the controls:

```
nlmeControl()

# this gives in my case the following settings
$maxIter
[1] 50

$pnlsMaxIter
[1] 7

$msMaxIter
[1] 50

$minScale
[1] 0.001

$tolerance
[1] 1e-05

$niterEM
[1] 25

$pnlsTol
[1] 0.001

$msTol
[1] 1e-06

$returnObject
[1] FALSE

$msVerbose
[1] FALSE

$gradHess
[1] TRUE

$apVar
[1] TRUE

$.relStep
[1] 6.055454e-06

$minAbsParApVar
[1] 0.05

$opt
[1] "nlminb"

$natural
[1] TRUE

$sigma
[1] 0
```

I haven't read any documentation, but you could at least run the following to get a better clue of the situation:

```
# using additional controls list argument
fm1 <- nlme(
  height ~ SSasymp(age, Asym, R0, lrc),
  data = Loblolly,
  fixed = Asym + R0 + lrc ~ 1,
  random = Asym ~ 1,
  start = c(Asym = -10311111, R0 = 8.5^4, lrc = 0.01),
  control = list(opt = "nlm", msVerbose = 2, msTol = 1e-06),
  verbose = TRUE
)
```

This would print you output for every iteration, finally:

```
# ............
iteration = 9
Parameter:
[1] 7.180326
Function Value
[1] 379.1821
Gradient:
[1] -4.212256e-05

Relative gradient close to zero.
Current iterate is probably solution.


**Iteration 1
LME step: Loglik: -312.2787, nlm iterations: 9
reStruct  parameters:
    Seed 
7.180326 
Error in nlme.formula(height ~ SSasymp(age, Asym, R0, lrc), data = Loblolly,  : 
  Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1
```

Maybe you want to modify `msTol` or other controls as well. Note that `nlm` allows to return the hessian too, if I print that I get:

```
$hessian
             [,1]
[1,] 8.478483e-05
```

If you wonder how I got the hessian printed, for my part I am editing `nlme.formula` and assigning my new version to a function called `nlme.formula_new`, which I then plug back into `nlme`:

```
godmode:::assignAnywhere("nlme.formula", nlme.formula_new)
```

`godmode` is on Github, but for sure there are other ways to achieve this.